# How to set detect with draggable function?

Tags: jquery

How to set detect with draggable function, When check the box the draggable function still not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/KPnRc/

HTML

```
<div class="drag" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:blue;"></div>
Lock:<input name="lock" id="lock" type="checkbox" value="0" />
```

JS

```
if($('#lock').is(':checked') == true){

    $(".drag").draggable();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your javascript in an onchange event
Here is a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/KPnRc/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {                 // When the document is ready
    $('.drag').draggable();                     // Initialize the .drag element with draggable
    $('#lock').on('change', function (evt) {    //Bind a function to the checkbox
        if($(this).is(':checked') == true) { //if checked then disable draggable
            $('.drag').draggable('disable');
        }
        else {                                  //else enable draggable.
            $('.drag').draggable('enable');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When you check the box it works then if you uncheck the box it will not work!

Comment: try it again.    I made a change as i forgot to add the 'enable' to paramter of draggable.

Comment: One more question, if I want to add "stop: function() { alert('stop');}", how to work with 'enable'??

Comment: hey Im happy to help but feel your abusing this site.  Have a look at the documentation for Draggable you will see two perfect examples on how to bind to the stop function http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#events